# how group by with common values into 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas

i've a csv file of 2 columns like that : (an animal can have many class but if it present several times in the same class we must count it only one time).

```
animal_id class
65HddD   class-a
65HddD   class-a
65HddD   class-b
65HddD   class-c
7DHSKQ   class-d
7DHSKQ   class-e
7DHSKQ   class-f
9JSJSZ   class-g
ZDKSKS   class-h
9SJSSF   class-i
ZSKSSS   class-j
9SJSSZ   class-k
... etc
```

i search to obtain a dataframe like that (where the values it's the number of unique animals common at two class) :

for example the value 20 below it's the number of unique animals present both into class-a and class-b. and the value 40 the number of unique animal present only in class-a (but we don't must count more one time an animal present 2 times in same class)

```
             class-a class-b class-c class-d class-n
    class-a  40       20     VALUE
    class-b 
    class-c
    class-d
    class-n
```

i've tried that but without success :

```py
import pandas as pd

animals_groups = pd.read_csv("animals.csv", sep="\s+") 

animals_groups.pivot_table(values="animal_id", index="class", columns="class", aggfunc="nunique")
```

Comment: sorry, crosstab is not used for `nunique`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df.merge(df, on='animal_id')
df = df.pivot_table(values="animal_id", 
                    index="class_x", 
                    columns="class_y", 
                    aggfunc="nunique",
                    fill_value=0)
```

---

```
print (df)
class_y  class-a  class-b  class-c  class-d  class-e  class-f  class-g  \
class_x                                                                  
class-a        1        1        1        0        0        0        0   
class-b        1        1        1        0        0        0        0   
class-c        1        1        1        0        0        0        0   
class-d        0        0        0        1        1        1        0   
class-e        0        0        0        1        1        1        0   
class-f        0        0        0        1        1        1        0   
class-g        0        0        0        0        0        0        1   
class-h        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   
class-i        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   
class-j        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   
class-k        0        0        0        0        0        0        0   

class_y  class-h  class-i  class-j  class-k  
class_x                                      
class-a        0        0        0        0  
class-b        0        0        0        0  
class-c        0        0        0        0  
class-d        0        0        0        0  
class-e        0        0        0        0  
class-f        0        0        0        0  
class-g        0        0        0        0  
class-h        1        0        0        0  
class-i        0        1        0        0  
class-j        0        0        1        0  
class-k        0        0        0        1
```

Comment: thanks for your quickly response it's exactly that !